# Read multiple values from a file into one variable

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I have an txt file which i am reading integers from. The text file is set out like this:

Paris
3

10

15

13

"Paris" indicates the destination
"2" is the number of stops
and the 3 number after are the amount in minutes between each stop.

(ps. there are no spaces between each line in the file)

I want to read in all the amount of minutes into a variable and add them, the program should be able to adapt it there are any changes to the amount of stops or the length.

The code i have so far:

```
while (inFile.hasNext()) {

    String inLine = inFile.nextLine();
    if(destination.equals(inLine)){

        String inStops = inFile.nextLine();
        int stops = Integer.parseInt(inStops);

        for (int i = 0; i > stops+1; i++){

         }
```

The destination is what the user has inputted earlier.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get best results if you ask a specific question. It's not clear in your question what you need help with. Is it calculating the total length? Or differentiating between the destination and number of stops?

Comment: @sprinter hi, sorry, im not very good at explaining. I am trying to find the total length then later in the code compare it with user input but i know how to do that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to add up the total length then it should just be a matter of reading each line and adding to the total:

```
int stops = Integer.parseInt(line);
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stops + 1; i++)
    total += Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
```

There's a lot of error checking missing from that code but it should give you an idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can sum the numbers from you txt.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(yourFile);
int sum=0;
while(yourFile.hasNext()){

String num = input.nextLine();
if(num=='Paris'){
break;}
int textNum = Integer.parseInt(num);
sum += textNum;
}
```